# Submit button is not invoking to php isset method

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I have a login page here in which there are two fields and a submit button. The code looks fine but when I press the submit button nothing is passed to the isset method. Here are my codes.

```php
<?php
function security($database,$value)
{
 $new_val=stripslashes($value);
 $new_val=mysqli_real_escape_string($database,$value);
 return $new_val;
}
require_once("database.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
  echo "working";
 $username=security("betit",$_POST['username']);
 $paassword=security("betit",$_POST['password']);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
 $result=mysqli_query("betit",$sql);
 if($result)
 {
  echo "congrats";
 }
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>LOGIN</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h3>Login</h3>
    <div class="col-3"> 
      <form method="post" action="" >
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
          <input id="email" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></i></span>
          <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">
     </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The database.php

```php
<?php
function db_connection($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
{

$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);


if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}


echo "Connect Successfullyworking. Host info: " . mysqli_get_host_info($link);
}
db_connection("localhost", "root", "", "betit")
?>
```

Submit button was supposed to invoke the isset method but nothing is passing.I just cant identify what kind of error is it.

Answer (score 0):

You have given type as button on submit input. change it to type="submit"

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in Button

Change

```
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">
```

To

```
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">
```